# A text/audio/video chat client that can connect to an IP directly?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, software-rec, ubuntu-10.04, chat

Is there any chat client that would just let you connect to someone's computer directly? (provided they're also running the same client). I'm in a place where I can connect to their ip directly, but none of the chat clients work (restricted internet access).

Edit: I use Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04. Looking for something that preferably works across (at least) these two platforms.

Comment: Since I have to guess what OS, I'm going to go with [RSTS/E](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSTS/E), but I'm not familiar with chat software for it. If, on the off chance that you're using Windows or OS X, here's a link to a video chat program (unfortunately it seems inactive) called [SquidCam](http://www.weblopedia.com/squidcam/download.cfm) which I've used before.

Comment: Use a standard SIP/H.323 client?

Comment: I don't think there's a huge market for this so I doubt something would have been developed to do such a job. I do like the idea though. (hint that I've added it to my future project list)

Answer (score 0):

Linphone works okay on both of those platforms.  I think what he was asking is about how some clients won't call directly like ekiga.  Anyway, I KNOW that linphone will allow direct calls.  Bear in mind NAT breaks SIP

Answer (score 0):

Set up an XMPP (jabber) server on one or both of the computers. Bear in mind that if you're behind a NAT router you'll need to forward some ports to get this (or anything like it, in fact) to work. Note that for voice/video you'll need an add-on to your client. A list of servers is [here](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/) (I use ejabberd) and you can find clients everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Originally answered to a different different question:
https://superuser.com/questions/621229/secure-pc-to-pc-voice-call-without-going-through-a-server/621285#621285

---

[Linphone](http://www.linphone.org) should do the trick. It supports call encryption via [ZRTP](http://www.gnutelephony.org/index.php/GNU_ZRTP). NAT traversal is easy with it via specifying a STUN server (i.e. stun.ekiga.net). It's super easy to set up. However, as it is SIP based, you will need a SIP server to go through. Personally, I just use sip.linphone.org as my proxy.

However, you should be able to set up [SIP Witch](http://www.gnutelephony.org/index.php/GNU_SIP_Witch) on both computers to allow direct peer-to-peer communication without any 3rd party servers. See, for example, their documentation on how to [set up SIP Witch on Ubuntu](http://www.gnutelephony.org/index.php/Howto_Deploy_SIP_Witch_On_Ubuntu) and adapt the instructions to your distro. Here's a better description of [how to set up SIP Witch for a home network](http://www.gnutelephony.org/index.php/GNU_SIP_Witch_configuration).